# VBA Range.Offset issue

Tags: excel, vba

I am having trouble with the following code:

```
Sub UseDictionary()

    ' Get the range of values
    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = Range("A2:B7")
    
    ' Create the dictionary
    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    ' Fill the dictionary
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In rg
        dict(cell.Value) = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
    Next
    
    ' Perform the Lookups
    For Each cell In rg
        Debug.Print cell.Value, dict(cell.Value)
    Next

End Sub
```

The problem is that when the line `dict(cell.Value) = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value` is processing a cell that is on column `B`, the dictionary item is created using the values of columns `B` and `C`.

How is that possible, since I set rg with only two columns `A` and `B`?! I thought Excel would not create that item since `cell.Offset(0, 1).Value` should not exist when `cell` has column `B` as its column.

So, how do I prevent the dictionary from create the item when `cell.Offset(0, 1).Value` refers to column `C`, which do not exist in my rg object?

Thank you very much for any clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cell.Offset()` is computed relative to the range object `cell`. That object itself is independent of the object `rg` that you have set equal to `Range("A2:B7")`. The fact that you are looping over `rg` does not mean that the looping variable `cell` is somehow or other a child object of `rg`. There is no difference between `cell` when it refers to `B2` as part of that loop and `cell` when it is directly set equal to the same cell `B2` via `Set cell = Range("B2")`. In either case it is just a range variable referring to `B2` (so that `cell.Offset(0,1)` naturally refers to `C2`).

In your case you seem to want the keys to be in column `A` and the values in column `B`. If so, just change your `rg` to be `Set rg = Range("A2:A7")`.